# How to do this Windows Form Navigation

Tags: c#, winforms, navigation

I have a main form that has a toostrip with four buttons form1, form2, form3 and form4. in click events of these buttons i have added this code `FormOne frm1 = new FormOne(); frm1.Show();` and vice versa i have added buttons on other forms to navigate to others thats working well.

Q1: there is a problem in the fact that every time I press the mainform buttons, a new instance of the other form displays how to display only one instance not more

Q2: how to make invisible the 1st one form when the other form is visible?

Comment: Doesn't an MDI Container help? in Windows Form it normal to use a MDI container instead a simple form when you have a lot of dialogs/windows...

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: there is a problem in the fact that every time I press the mainform buttons, a new instance of the other form displays how to display only one instance not more

Save your Forms as instance members of the main form. Create them upon initialization, and display when your mouse button is clicked (as usual.)

> Q2: how to make invisible the 1st one form when the other form is visible?

Whichever Form you want to hide, call its `.Hide()` method.